# Recieve the integer values when float is needed(computing determinant with numpy arr)

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to create a programm computing the determinant of the matrix using raw python code and numpy array to compare with scipy function.My algotirhm is first to change matrix to the upper triangle and then computing the final answer.

I probably found the problem: all elements are computed in integer, which differentiates from the float a little bit.And, by the multiplication effect, I get such an answer.But how do I fix this thing?Just adding `float()` when computing the row elements still makes them integers for some reason.

```
def my_det(X):
    '''
    Parameters
    ----------
    X : array_like

    Returns
    -------
    det : float
        Determinant of `a`.
    Plan
    ----
    Iterate through columns, create nested loop to iterate through all elements below
    the main diagonal, assign a scaler according to the value, iterate through all 
    elements in the row to change them according to the scaler. Finally, compute
    determinant.

    '''

    dimensionX, dimensionY = X.shape
    if dimensionX == dimensionY:
        matrixCopy = X.copy()
        for i in range(dimensionX):  # make only the diagonal non-zero
            for getZero in range(i + 1, dimensionX):  # make all elements below i-th zero(i.e. getZero elment = 0)
                if matrixCopy[i, i] == 0:  # cheating to create very small value
                    matrixCopy[i, i] == 1.0e-18
                rowScaler = matrixCopy[getZero, i] / matrixCopy[i, i]  # to change the rows accordingly
                print(rowScaler)
                for j in range(dimensionX):  # change every element in the row
                    matrixCopy[getZero, j] = float(matrixCopy[getZero, j]) - float(rowScaler * matrixCopy[i, j])
                    print(matrixCopy[getZero, j])
            print(matrixCopy)
        det = 1.0
        for detNum in range(dimensionX):  # TADAAAAAAM
            det *= matrixCopy[detNum, detNum]
        return det
    else:
        print('ValueError: wrong dimensions')


# matrix = np.random.randint(50, size=(3, 3))
matrix = np.array([[39, 24, 16], [24, 45, 47], [2, 7, 28]])
# matrix = np.array([[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]])
print(matrix)
print(my_det(matrix))
```

Comment: Note, when you cheat to make a small value: `matrixCopy[i, i] == 1.0e-18`. You're using equality and not assignment here

Comment: @Primusa. Which is as unintentional as setting it to zero would be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

```
matrix = np.array([[39, 24, 16], [24, 45, 47], [2, 7, 28]])
```

to

```
matrix = np.array([[39.0, 24.0, 16.0], [24.0, 45.0, 47.0], [2.0, 7.0, 28.0]])
```

Comment: But what if this is just an example, and the real array is created elsewhere as an int array.

Comment: Then you would need to use .astype but now that I think about it .astype would probably be better either way since it takes less work to implement

Comment: I suggest using something like                         
 matrix = matrix.astype(float) since it does the same thing but with less typing and you could add it to the beginning of your function so you dont have to worry about converting before you call the function

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of standard approaches for turning arbitrary array-like input into floating point arrays.

- `matrix_copy = X.astype(np.inexact, copy=True)`. This will pass thru all the floating point types, and guarantee a copy. This is the option you want, because you need a copy of the array.
- `matrix_copy = np.asfarray(X)`. This will pass thru all the floating point types, but does not copy the array if the array is already of the right type. You don't want to use this version because it does not copy the data in all cases.

Comment: when fixing I recieved `TypeError: asfarray() got an unexpected keyword argument 'copy'`.Tried googling, found unrelated info.What's wrong?

Comment: @EndOfTheGlory. I've updated my answer. I will also submit a PR to numpy to get that missing parameter fixed.

Comment: @EndOfTheGlory. I've submitted a PR to numpy to fix the missing `copy` argument based on this question, and a couple of similar problems I've run into in the past: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/14966. We'll see how it goes.